# Opening files from networks with Libre office

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, pdf, microsoft-office

I am able to see all files (word/excel etc) through Dolphin/network: 
I am able to cut from network computers, and paste and then open in my system:

However all other files like PDF/photos etc open directly without cut/copy/paste/open.

I am using Kubuntu 14.04 LTS and Libre office that was bundled.

How do I solve it?

I am trying to replace a few computers with Linux instead of XP etc. And I'm stuck because of this.

Comment: What error do you get, if any?

Comment: Has LO write access on the network drive?

Comment: @S.S.Mani Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for your unregistered account and your new registered account to be merged. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess here... you're using an SMB share and when you click on a file in Dolphin, LibreOffice throws an error like "You can only select local files" or something similar.

There is a workaround. You need to comment out a line in all of the `/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-*.desktop` files. Open each file in an editor and type a pound sign (`#`) at the beginning of this line (to comment it out):

```
X-KDE-Protocols=file,http,smb,ftp,webdav
```

You'll need to do this as root, since root owns these files.

This workaround was reported in [LibreOffice bug 67527](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67527).